# Replacing variable values based on index variable from another dataset

Tags: r, dplyr, relational-database

I have two datasets that have a different number of cases, but the same number of variables. E.g., this:

```
test_data <- data.frame(
  var_1 = rep(1, 10),
  index = letters[1:10]
)

other_data <- data.frame(
  var_1 = c(1, 1, 3, 4, 6, 1),
  index = letters[1:6]
)
```

And what I need is to replace the values in `var_1` in `test_data` with the values of `var_1` in `other_data`. So the end result would look like this:

```
> test_data
   var_1 index
1      1     a
2      1     b
3      3     c
4      4     d
5      6     e
6      1     f
7      1     g
8      1     h
9      1     i
10     1     j
```

I know that `dplyr` is nice to work with relational data, but I can't figure out whether it's one of the `_join` function that would do it for me, or something different? Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just to add another answer:
Using Base R and `match`.

```
test_data$var_1=other_data$var_1[match(test_data$index, other_data$index)]
test_data[is.na(test_data)] = 1

   var_1 index
1      1     a
2      1     b
3      3     c
4      4     d
5      6     e
6      1     f
7      1     g
8      1     h
9      1     i
10     1     j
```

This will match values under `index` to get the value of `var_1` from `other_data` and then will replace the column `var_1` from `test_data` with the resultant values.

NA's will be generated 'cause in `index` column of `test_data` are more factors (letters) than in the `index` of `other_data`. So then we replace NA values with 1.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What is the var_1 is not  filled with 1? but different numbers?

Comment: yeah, I think I din't make it clear in my question – the `1`s are a placeholder,  there are actually many different numbers.

Answer (score -1):

You can use merge:

```
merged <- merge( test_data, other_data, by = c('index'), all.x = TRUE )
merged$var <- ifelse( is.na( merged$var_1.y ) , merged$var_1.x, merged$var_1.y )
merged[ , c('var', 'index')]
   var index
1    1     a
2    1     b
3    3     c
4    4     d
5    6     e
6    1     f
7    1     g
8    1     h
9    1     i
10   1     j
```